# How to push i times in an array of objects in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a data(`$scope.users`) that I displays in the view. When the `$scope.users` length is less than 5 it should display 2 empty rows with null input boxes to make it 5 rows. The goal of the page is to display 5 rows even the other data is null.

I used `$scope.users.push({})` to add. I also created a for loop but it only push a one row. It should add how many rows is needed.

What is wrong in my codes?

```js
var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.showRecords = function() {
        $scope.users = [{
            'id': 5,
            'username': 'ady',
            'role': 'Admin',
            'img': 'Jellyfish.jpg',
        }, {
            'id': 7,
            'username': 'tiu',
            'role': 'Admin',
            'img': 'Jellyfish.jpg',
        }, {
            'id': 4,
            'username': 'ert',
            'role': 'Admin',
            'img': 'Jellyfish.jpg',
        }];


        if ($scope.users.length < 5) {

            for (var i = 1; i < 5 - $scope.users.length; i++) {
                $scope.users.push({});
            }

        }

    }

    $scope.submit = function(users) {
        console.log(users);

    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="mymodal">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">


    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr ng-repeat="row in users">
        <!-- <td>{{row.id}}</td>
            <td>{{row.username}}</td>
            <td>{{row.role}}</td> -->
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="row.id" name="id">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="row.username" name="username">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="row.role" name="role">
        </td>

      </tr>
    </table>
    <button ng-click="showRecords();">Show Record</button>

    <button ng-click="submit(users);">Submit new record</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If length is `3` then you loops condition will be `i < 2`.

But you loop start from `1` and seek for `i < 2`.

After first iteration `i` will be `2` but your condition seeking value less then `2`

Convert this

```
i < 5 - $scope.users.length
```

to this

```
i <= 5 - $scope.users.length
```

Or start from 0 instead of 1

Like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5 - $scope.users.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `while` loops:

```
    while($scope.users.length < 5) {
            $scope.users.push({});
    }
```